# React packages don't work serving it as a static file through express?

Tags: reactjs, express, production-environment, okta, okta-api

This is an Okta question. I just thought I post here since Okta's community is very small and they can take weeks to reply. I'm hoping someone here has experience with them... Or maybe it's not an okta question and it's more a react production build question. Does React build/ PROD limit the use of its modules when serving it as a static file through express?

I have deployed my app using express.js on the backend and react.js on the front-end. After I ran 'npm run build' and reference the build directory from Express, I was able to get my app to render the react components through the server-side.

The issue here is when making calls to the '@okta/okta-react' package such as okta.signIn(), I first got a 401 api/ Authentication error thinking it was a CORs or related problem. After further debugging, starting up client-side (npm start (dev), NOT npx serve(prod)), the okta.signIn() works.

Does the '@okta/okta-react' package not work in Production? Is it because I'm serving this as a static file through express? What is the solution here? Do i have to implement the okta server side instead, if so, whats the purpose of the react package?

Reason for using express:

True HTTPS server-side
Mailer Integration
Other Third-party integration

Client side package.json

```
"scripts": {
 "start": "serve -s build -l 80",
 "build": "node scripts/build.js",
 "dev": "pm2 start scripts/start.js",
 "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
},
"proxy": "http://localhost:443",
```

app.js Server

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {    
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build/index.html'))
})
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure but let me try to answer your question. `Does the '@okta/okta-react' package not work in Production?` It should work in production as well. `Is it because I'm serving this as a static file through express?` What are you serving as static file? `index.html` which contains bundle script? 

I have a feeling your implementation is somewhere wrong. Can you please add some code as well?

Comment: @iRohitBhatia I've updated the post with some code. Please correct me, perhaps I'm referencing the build wrong or something. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are probably securing your API routes with

```
app.all('*', authenticationRequired);
```

This works fine in a local environment but in a production environment using static files you'll need to remove the above line.  The above line is securing all routes to your site with a token, even the login callback route before you have a token from OKTA.  Instead you'll need to secure the API routes  individually like the example below:

```
app.get('/api/hello', authenticationRequired,(req, res) => {
res.send('Hello world!');
});
```